# Access GutenBerg data with Javascript?

Tags: block-editor

**I am trying to find out where does Gutenberg save changes/settings/options and how to access them?**  in Javascript object, variable or HTML-DOM?

for example, whenever we choose category checkboxes, tags or change this or that  settings or options in Gutenberg blocks, where all those changes are saved in that moment?

Answer (score 2):

All datas seems to be stored in JS objects, and not in HTML-DOM. We can use:

```
wp.data.select("core").getXXXXXXXXXXXX()
wp.data.select("core/editor").getXXXXXXXXXXXX()
...
```

There are many areas too, you can list them with: `console.log(wp.blocks.getBlockTypes());`